# Cromis IPC Synchronization - Application stops responding

Tags: multithreading, delphi, windows-services, ipc, ado

I have a service application which connects to MSSQL using `TADOConnection` and provides client applications with some data using `Cromis.IPC`'s `TIPCServer` object. This service application might be installed on the same machine which is running MSSQL, and might start before `MSSQL` service. So, I can not connect to ADO in `OnServiceStart` event. I tried to connect to ADO in `OnExecuteRequest` event of `TIPCServer`, but since it is running in a separate thread, I got "CoInitialize has not been called". Then, I tried to synchronize this with my main thread like this:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil, ConnectDB);
```

but it didn't work. My application stops responding right there.

Next, I modified the `OnExecuteRequest` event to pass the thread which is calling it as a parameter, and I tried this:

```
AThread.Synchronize(AThread, ConnectDB);
```

But no change. When I turned on Use debug DCUs, I found out that my application stops responding on this line:

```
function WaitForSyncWaitObj(P: Pointer; Timeout: Cardinal): Integer;
begin
  Result := WaitForSingleObject(THandle(P), Timeout); // <-- I'm stuck here...
end;
```

I'm completely lost. Any ideas?

---

PS: I didn't provide my code to prevent cluttering the question. If you need any part of it, just let me know.

---

PS 2: Before this, I tried to use a Timer in my service application to wait for a period before connecting to MSSQL. It seems like MSSQL starts pretty soon, even before network drivers are loaded (I have McAfee VSE 8.7 installed which replaces the network driver). My service connects to MSSQL, but then, when the network driver is loaded, the connection is broken. If there is a way to tell windows (XP and later) to start a service *after* network driver is loaded, my problem is solved. Any hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Call `CoInitialize(nil);` in your `TThread` constructor, and `CoUnitialize` in it's destructor. Both of them are declared in the `ComObj` unit; you may need to add it to your `uses` clause in the unit containing the thread class.

Database connections are thread-specific (meaning each thread has to have it's own connection), and `ADO` requires COM; that means that the thread has to initialize COM for itself, and should release it when the thread ends.

Comment: I know about `CoInitialie()`, but I need to access the ADO connection from in my main thread too.

Comment: Then you need two separate connections. Once again, **database connections are thread-specific**. :-)

Comment: Imagine that I only need the ADO connection in my main thread. My question is why calling `Synchronize` hangs...